Pivot table filter applied to underlying table's rows
This problem arose while I was working in the Google Data Analytics certificate program.  You can apply a filter to a pivot table in Google Sheets and then use this to filter out rows from the underlying table (using a "Less Than" in the Value Filter setting).  This filter then flows through to the pivot table to produce a change in the aggregated values (SUM, COUNT, etc.) for each (pivot table) row.
When I tried to do this in Excel, it would not let me filter on the underlying table rows: you can only apply this Value Filter (Less Than) to the aggregated value in the pivot table.  For example, with a pivot table with customers in the Rows and customer orders in the Values quadrant, you are able to filter only on Summarized aggregates (such as the SUM of all the order Sales values) in the pivot table but not on the individual orders (or Sales values) in the underlying table itself.
I even tried to apply the filter to the underlying table and then apply the pivot table.  But the pivot table results ignored the filter; it didn't flow through.  If I tried to filter out the customer orders of a given value, the Summarized aggregates still only applied to the entire aggregate of each customer's orders.
Google Sheets allows you to reference the underlying table with using "Less Than" in the pivot table filter.  Is this not able to be done in Excel?
Finally (in response to teylyn) it's more like a "feature question": I want to know if it's possible to create such a filter (by using the Value Filter "Less Than" option rather than having to manually deselect possibly thousands of rows), because I have already spent quite a few hours trying to figure out if it is.  And if it is possible, knowing how to use this feature in Excel could save even more hours in the future, if I ever need such a filter.  So it's an Excel problem as well.

Is there a question in there somewhere? It looks more like a feature request, which you should direct towards Microsoft. You are posting in a site for programming, and your question is not in any way about programming. Hence I vote to close your question.
